# Creating a type-safe and maintainable config file for C++

Tags: c++, struct, config

I have a nested struct representing a configuration, say:

```cpp
typedef struct Config_t {
  bool IsOK = true;

  struct Server_t {
    string Address = "192.168.1.50";
    unsigned short Port = 9000;

    // macro sets up serialization for a struct by member
    // by adding << and >> operators.
    ALLOW_SERIAL(Server_t, Address, Port)
  } Server;

  struct Controller_t {
    float Speed = 42.0;

    ALLOW_SERIAL(Controller_t, Speed)
  } Controller;

  ALLOW_SERIAL(Config_t, IsOK, Server, Controller)
} Config_t;

// serialization
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Config_t cfg) { /* ... */ }

// deserialization
ifstream& operator>>(ifstream& is, Config_t& cfg) { /* ... */ }
```

I have some wrapper class, `ConfigWrapper`, which has a `Config_t`. It does the following:

```cpp
class ConfigWrapper {
private:
  Config_t cfg_;
  string file_;

public:
  ConfigWrapper(string file): file_(file) {
    ifstream if(file_);
    if >> cfg;
  }
  ~ConfigWrapper() {
    ofstream of(file_);
    of << cfg;
  }
  Config_t& Config() { return cfg_; } // BAD data race
};
```

Users have an instance of `ConfigWrapper` somehow (singleton or DI or something).

They can set/get config items my modifying the reference from `ConfigWrapper::Config()`.

This is pretty nice, but does not work in a multi-threaded application where multiple users could edit settings concurrently.

What are my options for a better design for the `ConfigWrapper`/`Config_t` classes? I'm not above some macro trickery, but am looking for the following properties:

1. Statically typed access/mutation, like the struct provides (rather than `::Get<bool>("IsOK")`)
2. Easy to add new properties/default values (would prefer to avoid getters/setters for every property)
3. Mutex access to properties (or maybe a rw lock?)
4. (bonus) Easy to add serialization for user-made data types

Can I have my cake and eat it too? Which of these properties will I probably have to lose? Is there a way to do this with macro magic?

Comment: Making things thread-safe comes to a price (aka. performance impact) which is annoying if you don't know whether a utility class is used with or without multi-threading. So, you may drop the requirement of thread-safety and use thread-safe accessors for your config if necessary. Another option is [Policy-based design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_C%2B%2B_Design#Policy-based_design). - I just recently saw that e.g. in the [nano-sig-slot](https://github.com/NoAvailableAlias/nano-signal-slot#threading-policies) where thread-safety is a policy parameter (to give an example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used `operator->` to achieve some similar things before. We can let it return a proxy class that locks a mutex and also dereferences to the underlying `Config_t` object.

```
class ConfigWrapper {
private:
  Config_t cfg_;
  string file_;
  std::mutex mux;

  class MutexWrapper {
      private:
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg;
      Config_t& cfg;
      MutexWrapper(std::mutex& m, Config_t& c) : lg(m), cfg(c) {}
      MutexWrapper(const MutexWrapper&) = delete;

      friend ConfigWrapper;

      public:
      Config_t* operator->() {
          return &cfg;
      }
  };

public:
  ConfigWrapper(string file): file_(file) {
    ifstream if(file_);
    if >> cfg;
  }
  ~ConfigWrapper() {
    ofstream of(file_);
    of << cfg;
  }
  Config_t& Config() { return cfg_; } // BAD data race

  MutexWrapper operator->() {
      return {mux, cfg_};
  }
};

int main() {
    ConfigWrapper cw;
    cw->Controller.Speed = 3.14;
}
```

`cw->` will return a `MutexWrapper` that locks our mutex and since it also has a `operator->` it will be called and finally the returned pointer to `Config_t` is dereferenced.

Thet remporary will live until the end of the full expression and unlock the mutex after the assignment is done, giving you synchronized access to the underlying struct.

Comment: Thoughts on getting this to work elegantly with a `ConfigWrapper*` or a `shared_ptr<ConfigWrapper>`? The `operator->()` chaining stops at the raw pointer.